# Average rate of change over the given interval?

Tags: derivatives

Find the average rate of change for the following functions please. I'm facing problems in these.

1. $s=2t^3-5t+7$ interval from $t=1$ to $t=3$
2. $h=\sqrt{2t}-7$ interval from $t=8$ to $t=8.5$

Comment: I solved it using the formula "delta y/delta x=(f(x+delta x)-f(x))/delta x" and the answer came 21 and 2 respectively but my book answer is 17 and .25 for each.

Comment: It looks like your first answer is correct.  Unless there's a typo in the formula, the book seems to be wrong.  For your second answer, the book is correct.  Did you forget to take the square-root in your calculation?

Comment: yes my mistake, apart from sqr. thanks

Answer (score 1):

When I want to find the average of five numbers, I take their sum and divide it by five. It looks like this: $$\frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5}{5}.$$ You've been asked to find the average value of a function, the rates of change or derivatives of $s$ and $h$.

Note that the values of a function are also a set of points, though in your case there are categorically more than five of them. Can you think of a way to do something *like* adding all of the values of the derivative between those bounds and then dividing by the *size* of the set of values?

**Edit:** You've been given two functions defined for $t$ in the real numbers. You can think of $t$ like time, which is to say not discrete. In your comment, you refer to the only value of $t$ between $1$ and $3$ as being $2$, though there are many more. Take $2.5$ and $1.3$ for example.

The rates of change of $s(t)$ and $h(t)$ are given by their derivatives. Can you calculate those? Then, to get the average value you have to *add*, which is to say *integrate* these functions between the given bounds and then divide by the length of the interval $3-1 = 2$.

The comment below gives a simpler and better answer than mine, though the two are equivalent.

Comment: I didn't understand. i'm totally new to derivatives. Are you talking about the values between the interval "t=1 to t=3"? there is just one value between them "2"

Comment: I've addressed your comment in an edit to my answer.

Comment: The average rate of change of a function does *not* involve derivatives.  The average rate of change of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is simply $\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$.

Comment: Oops! Got ahead of myself. Thanks for catching that. Though, if you notice, our answers our the same...

Comment: show me the exact average change in it please?